# extract mth entry from nth line in a matrix in multiple text files and write values to a new text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, data-extraction

I have numerous text files each containing a matrix, with entries separated by tabs & spaces (below is an example of a 31x31 matrix from one file).  The line length in the file is limited to 80 chars so the matrix in each file is split into sections, 5 columns in each section.  The row and column labels are the same but the values are different in each file.

I've used awk, tac, and sed to extract each matrix from much larger text files and I can use grep to extract rows starting with "n", but I get multiple matches.

How do I extract a single value from the matrix, e.g. the value from column-m, row-n?

Example matrix (if I want the value from column-label-4, row-label-19 it is 0.170506e+03 but I don't want column-label-9, row-label-19, etc).

```
            1             2             3             4             5 
  1  0.000000e+00
  2  0.721521e+02  0.000000e+00
  3  0.600476e+02  0.128509e+01  0.000000e+00
  4  0.456807e+01  0.680774e+02  0.684277e+01  0.000000e+00
  5 -0.182269e+01  0.931860e+01  0.559086e+02 -0.242923e+01  0.000000e+00
  6  0.584994e+01 -0.197137e+00 -0.143585e+01  0.560372e+02  0.550432e+02
  7  0.542294e+02  0.262080e+01  0.157417e+01  0.286038e+01  0.354815e+01
  8 -0.910697e+00 -0.171964e+01 -0.226769e+01  0.234255e+00  0.353624e+00
  9  0.127740e+02 -0.660645e+00  0.105756e+01  0.138880e+00  0.394360e+00
 10 -0.567264e+01  0.266271e+02 -0.699972e+00 -0.241535e+01 -0.489788e+00
 11  0.164453e+01 -0.268724e+01 -0.937484e+00  0.216974e+01  0.106543e+01
 12 -0.151676e+00  0.354374e+01 -0.209327e-01 -0.195212e+00  0.202971e-01
 13  0.273307e-01 -0.203135e+00 -0.110701e-01  0.861538e-01 -0.110135e-01
 14 -0.573171e-02  0.214964e-01 -0.184033e-01  0.364860e-01  0.606920e-02
 15  0.283181e-03 -0.681593e-01 -0.119171e-01 -0.686958e-02 -0.806671e-02
 16 -0.179097e-01  0.546512e-01 -0.100820e-01 -0.920151e-02 -0.545025e-02
 17 -0.680697e-02  0.330910e-01 -0.882713e-02 -0.702130e-02 -0.904883e-02
 18  0.191358e+01  0.897776e+01  0.174601e+03 -0.160680e+01  0.132934e+01
 19  0.501936e+01 -0.148977e+01 -0.106646e+01  0.170506e+03  0.788318e+01
 20  0.750686e+01 -0.187707e+01  0.372143e+01  0.779846e+01  0.171860e+03
 21 -0.176860e+01  0.970217e+01  0.842497e+01  0.298143e+01  0.224798e+01
 22  0.277835e+01 -0.277276e-01  0.969619e+00 -0.622222e-01  0.282413e+00
 23 -0.313601e-01  0.159815e+00  0.128057e+00 -0.108106e+00 -0.142940e+00
 24 -0.664854e+00 -0.103596e+00 -0.525825e+00 -0.150942e+00 -0.168649e+00
 25  0.238097e+00 -0.203976e+00  0.139855e+00 -0.223460e+00 -0.160727e+00
 26  0.939240e-01  0.520710e+01  0.143495e+00  0.474836e+00 -0.177345e-01
 27 -0.217367e-01 -0.193976e-01 -0.402727e-01 -0.116617e-01 -0.391614e-01
 28  0.215782e-01 -0.257971e-01 -0.524527e-02  0.847063e-02 -0.812533e-02
 29 -0.351691e-01 -0.201438e-01 -0.349724e-01 -0.349667e-01 -0.404346e-01
 30 -0.242743e-01  0.273895e-01 -0.272225e-01 -0.321191e-01 -0.270577e-01
 31 -0.426292e-01 -0.650232e-01 -0.353929e-01 -0.500703e-01 -0.408613e-01
            6             7             8             9            10 
  6  0.000000e+00
  7 -0.936388e+00  0.000000e+00
  8 -0.771894e+00  0.347601e+02  0.000000e+00
  9 -0.780112e-02  0.398653e+02 -0.240450e+01  0.000000e+00
 10 -0.392030e+00  0.810380e+00  0.197957e+00 -0.160651e+01  0.000000e+00
 11 -0.104303e+01 -0.473339e+00 -0.181607e+00 -0.779374e-01  0.226143e+02
 12 -0.418416e-02  0.624987e-02  0.108646e-01  0.296996e-01 -0.666498e+01
 13 -0.164417e-02  0.805055e-02 -0.327675e-02  0.224641e+00 -0.228145e+01
 14 -0.896018e-02  0.467393e-02 -0.116081e-01  0.402774e-01 -0.187870e+01
 15 -0.165742e-01  0.116181e-01  0.491196e-02  0.149563e-02  0.192684e+00
 16 -0.108811e-01  0.914469e-02 -0.545833e-02 -0.108184e-02 -0.210964e+00
 17 -0.781403e-02 -0.580951e-02  0.118073e-02  0.154451e-02 -0.486910e+00
 18  0.897380e+01  0.424211e+01 -0.172328e+00 -0.184136e+00 -0.138291e+01
 19  0.657396e+00  0.147826e+01 -0.523860e-01 -0.111425e+00 -0.128888e+01
 20  0.288321e+01  0.315703e+00 -0.304020e-01  0.395279e+00  0.305902e+00
 21  0.172066e+03  0.353312e+00  0.257543e+00 -0.827528e-01 -0.546139e+00
 22 -0.173817e+00 -0.561225e+01 -0.231104e+01  0.132923e+03 -0.212803e+01
 23  0.678972e-01 -0.325811e+01 -0.333356e+01  0.132717e+03 -0.117255e+01
 24 -0.364090e-01 -0.559051e+01 -0.226053e+01  0.135664e+03 -0.191640e+01
 25  0.288697e-01 -0.154002e-01  0.732688e-01  0.389421e-01 -0.649423e+01
 26  0.329439e-01  0.113114e+00 -0.489852e-01  0.437129e-02 -0.178242e+01
 27 -0.350781e-01  0.331257e-01  0.692445e-01  0.162228e+00 -0.233797e+00
 28 -0.105914e-01  0.449153e-01 -0.421949e-01 -0.847419e-02  0.406464e+00
 29 -0.346255e-01 -0.126815e-01  0.298766e-01 -0.190825e-02 -0.931165e-01
 30 -0.306026e-01 -0.103474e-01 -0.750491e-02 -0.276690e-01 -0.387865e+00
 31 -0.391694e-01 -0.160436e-01  0.129641e-01 -0.278777e-01  0.273425e+00
           11            12            13            14            15 
 11  0.000000e+00
 12  0.467564e+02  0.000000e+00
 13  0.881448e+00  0.579819e+02  0.000000e+00
 14  0.716385e+01  0.607427e+02 -0.991284e+00  0.000000e+00
 15  0.287998e+01 -0.194597e+01  0.565281e+02  0.934983e+01  0.000000e+00
 16  0.463881e+01 -0.181340e+01  0.936084e+01  0.570706e+02 -0.196049e+01
 17 -0.832936e+00  0.976863e+01 -0.230035e+01 -0.238944e+01  0.563671e+02
 18  0.347788e+00 -0.479532e-01 -0.301202e-01 -0.153968e-01 -0.317186e-01
 19 -0.613594e+00 -0.614702e-01 -0.591356e-02 -0.214354e-01 -0.272421e-01
 20 -0.798555e+00 -0.729967e-01 -0.474076e-01 -0.464470e-01 -0.396436e-01
 21  0.344045e+00  0.304264e-01 -0.320892e-01 -0.199989e-01 -0.343410e-01
 22 -0.139634e+00 -0.155831e-02  0.451784e-01  0.122067e-01  0.391645e-01
 23 -0.134584e-01  0.977362e-01  0.117129e+00 -0.112740e-01  0.573879e-01
 24  0.665500e-01  0.205558e+00  0.291200e+00  0.203071e+00  0.185938e+00
 25  0.153013e+03 -0.385235e+01  0.209834e+01  0.268836e+01 -0.176283e+01
 26  0.142234e+03 -0.500715e+01  0.583433e+01  0.533312e+01  0.248117e+00
 27  0.369337e+01  0.145248e+01  0.169852e+03  0.667599e+01  0.211325e+01
 28  0.506080e+01  0.185510e+01  0.654919e+01  0.167717e+03 -0.133186e+01
 29  0.423633e+00  0.746968e+01  0.289356e+01 -0.155984e+01  0.169140e+03
 30  0.836116e+00  0.788074e+01 -0.154829e+01  0.321592e+01  0.768037e+01
 31  0.492733e+00 -0.167308e+01  0.769284e+01  0.771146e+01  0.274931e+01
           16            17            18            19            20 
 16  0.000000e+00
 17  0.563437e+02  0.000000e+00
 18 -0.277881e-01 -0.310893e-01  0.000000e+00
 19 -0.468903e-01 -0.349754e-01  0.674547e-01  0.000000e+00
 20 -0.356008e-01 -0.399449e-01  0.811357e+01  0.392889e+00  0.000000e+00
 21 -0.286906e-01 -0.390021e-01  0.982516e+00  0.850918e+01  0.770379e+01
 22 -0.203361e-02  0.179088e-01 -0.123824e+00 -0.325991e+00 -0.126917e+00
 23 -0.183104e-01 -0.239046e-01 -0.232345e+00 -0.960356e-01 -0.229829e+00
 24  0.681006e-01  0.727167e-01 -0.256214e+00 -0.111619e+00 -0.344057e+00
 25 -0.136226e+01  0.151444e+01 -0.316609e+00  0.782397e+00 -0.204809e+00
 26 -0.225132e+00  0.345762e+00 -0.151636e+00  0.203399e+00 -0.125574e+00
 27 -0.137205e+01  0.759751e+01 -0.156822e+00  0.861828e-01 -0.164811e+00
 28  0.183143e+01  0.740244e+01 -0.735917e-01 -0.173018e-01 -0.960416e-01
 29  0.774362e+01  0.275865e+01 -0.141085e+00 -0.948004e-01 -0.145096e+00
 30  0.169995e+03  0.256469e+01 -0.110523e+00 -0.130983e+00 -0.125583e+00
 31  0.262752e+01  0.168413e+03 -0.137933e+00 -0.152079e+00 -0.141287e+00
           21            22            23            24            25 
 21  0.000000e+00
 22 -0.233295e+00  0.000000e+00
 23 -0.302229e+00 -0.117659e+02  0.000000e+00
 24 -0.312839e+00 -0.176690e+02 -0.189160e+02  0.000000e+00
 25 -0.824478e-01 -0.283764e+00 -0.471927e-01 -0.276491e+00  0.000000e+00
 26 -0.166512e+00 -0.203046e+00 -0.165616e+00  0.266305e+00 -0.146540e+02
 27 -0.109422e+00  0.721405e-02  0.545424e+00  0.526054e+00 -0.123076e+01
 28 -0.750264e-01 -0.135673e+00 -0.160647e+00  0.100742e+00 -0.118033e+01
 29 -0.135413e+00 -0.296749e-02  0.458369e-01  0.741089e-01  0.247293e+00
 30 -0.124059e+00 -0.112653e+00 -0.192132e+00 -0.549934e-01  0.318556e+00
 31 -0.143265e+00 -0.841207e-01 -0.136539e+00 -0.619821e-01 -0.141302e+01
           26            27            28            29            30 
 26  0.000000e+00
 27 -0.934817e+00  0.000000e+00
 28  0.172890e+00  0.118621e+01  0.000000e+00
 29  0.126856e+00  0.807384e+01  0.223449e+00  0.000000e+00
 30  0.345871e-01  0.259443e+00  0.796643e+01  0.609036e+00  0.000000e+00
 31 -0.636999e+00  0.563246e+00  0.501209e+00  0.766542e+01  0.777868e+01
           31 
 31  0.000000e+00
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v row=19 -v col=4 '
    # a header row contains only blanks and digits
    ! /[^[:blank:][:digit:]]/ {
        if ($1 <= col && col <= $NF) {
          for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i == col) field=i+1 }
        }
        next
    }
    $1 == row && field {print $field; exit}
' file
```

```
0.170506e+03
```

Comment: Checking for a period might be more robust, in case the "e" is dropped or replaced by "E".

Comment: That update doesn't look quite right. I'd keep it simple and just check for "." (or a non-whitespace or non-digit).  Also, you could avoid executing the loop in all but one case by comparing $NF with col.

Comment: The "non-whitespace/digit" is a good observation. I don't understand your comment about the loop though. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $NF is too small, then there's no need to start the loop.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my editing the script -- there was a small but serious bug that had the potential to spread.

Comment: what was the bug? Looks to me like you've reduced the efficiency a bit.

Comment: I've re-instated the test as you had it, but it belongs in the ACTION part of the CONDITION ACTION rule.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did: the `next` command should have be outside of the overall condition. That "bug" does not affect the output, since that relies on the `field` variable being defined to a non-zero value. The braces around the body of the for-loop can safely be omitted since it is a single statement.  Revision #6 is still correct.

Comment: Yes, I see now that the "bug" was only a minor performance issue.  Sorry about that. Regarding the braces, see e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Comment: That seems to be a rather religious debate, but I'll not argue it. Why didn't you put braces around `field=i+1`? Consistency.

Comment: This works on the sample data in my query but not on the original file (some of the spacing/tabs got lost in the copy-paste).  Thanks for your help though, it gave me enough of an idea to get a working script.  With some variables to do some calculations to identify the correct line in the data file, the final line in the script is: awk -v line="$findline" -v column="$colcount" 'FNR==line {print $column}' $filename.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the tabs are being used as field separators and the spaces for layout.  If that is the case, then the following would provide a more generic solution in the sense that the matrix elements can be anything at all:

```
awk -F\\t -v row=19 -v col=19 '
    # a header row is assumed to have "" in column 1
    0+$1 == 0 {
        # Guard against trailing tabs:
        while (NF>1 && 0+$NF == 0) {NF--}
        if (col <= $NF) { field = 2 + col - $2}
        next
    }
    $1 == row && field {print $field; exit}
'
```

}

This also computes the value of `col` directly rather than searching for it, though this is at the cost of having to check for trailing tabs.

(You might consider modifying the format so that headers can be detected reliably, e.g. by having '0' in the first field.)